# write variable to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to write df_filter  to excell. All things are completed. At These final step i am struggling. Please do the need full help

1. In this i am trying to read list of excel files in a directory.
2. doing filtering(from config.csv)
3. is need write **'df_filter'** to excel Below code i have tried.i am caliing sheets function many time.every iteration df_filter write into excel

code

```
 df_filter = pd.DataFrame(columns=['packetsize', 'throughput', 'latency (us)', 'jitter (us)'])
    def sheets(val):

    s = wb.worksheets[val]

    HeaderList = pd.read_csv(config_path)

    column_list = []
    for col in HeaderList:
        col = col.lstrip("'")
        col = col.rstrip("'")
        column_list.append(col)

    df1 = xl.parse(sheet_list[val], skiprows=i)
    df1 = df1.filter(column_list)

    df2 = df1[(df1['Result'] != 'Failed') & (df1['Frame Size Type'] == 'iMIX')]

    if df2.empty:
        pass
    else:
        final3 = df2.groupby(['Trial Number', 'iMIX Distribution'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Throughput (%)'].idxmax()])

        final = df2.groupby(['iMIX Distribution'], sort=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['Throughput (%)'].idxmax()])
        df_filter['packetsize'] = final.apply(lambda z: '%s' % (z['iMIX Distribution']), axis=1)


        df_filter['throughput'] = final.apply(lambda z: '%s' % (z['Throughput (%)']), axis=1)
        df_filter['latency (us)'] = final.apply(lambda x: '%s/%s/%s' % (x['Minimum Latency (us)'], x['Maximum Latency (us)'], x['Average Latency (us)']),axis=1)
        df_filter['jitter (us)'] = final.apply(lambda y: '%s/%s/%s' % (y['Minimum Jitter (us)'], y['Maximum Jitter (us)'], y['Average Jitter (us)']),axis=1)
        #return df_filter
```

Comment: It will help if the question is more specific rather than posting the full script. Perhaps debugging with Pycharm can help - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/starting-the-debugger-session.html

Comment: What binithb said. Please also read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)